# Class consist out of four parts seperated by spaces

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web site using python and beautiful soup. The goal is to build a csv file, with the relevant information(location, unit size, rent...)
 I am not 100% sure what the problem is but I think it has to do with the strutcture of the class. "result matches_criteria_and_filters first_listing highlighted"

First part of the code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 r= requests.get("https://www.publicstorage.com/storage-search-landing.aspx? 
 location=New+York")
 c=r.content
```

After that I would need the class= result matches_criteria_and_filters first_listing highlighted. Here I am not able to do it.

Solutions that I found in other threads were not working.

```
 soup.select("result.matches_criteria_and_filters.first_listing.highlighted")
```

Another possibility I found is to seperate, but it did not work.

```
 soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'result'})
 soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'matches_criteria_and_filters'})
```

Everything I tried, gave empty or none objects.

Answer (score 0):

First try getting the parent div by the code similar to the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('yourhtml', 'lxml')
results_div = soup.find('div', {'id':'results'})
#now iterate through all children divs
```

then do whatever you want to do with children divs